# Slider Bars move equally

Tags: tkinter, canvas, widget, slider, scale

good day ..

I am trying to introduce 3 slider bars,  in canvas using tkinter, but they move equally, I need use the values as real numbers, not integer nor strings, and I define Variables, v1, v2, v3, in scale command, to be able to use like float, but this is causing the problem, that they move equally, but how can I get they move one by one.  this is my code.. can somebody explain me what can I do.. thanks a lot for any help...

```
`Main Menu Canvas
from math import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from OpenGL import *

3d Graphics

root3d=Tk()
root3d.title('3D_View')

canvas2 = Canvas(root3d, width=350, height=350, bg='grey35', borderwidth=3) 
canvas2.pack()

v1 = float()
v2 = float()
v3 = float()

wx1 = Scale(root3d, variable = v1, from_= -3.141592, to= 3.141592, orient=HORIZONTAL, digit=5)
wx1.pack()

wx2 = Scale(root3d, variable = v2, from_= -3.141592, to= 3.141592, orient=HORIZONTAL, digit=5)
wx2.pack()

wx3 = Scale(root3d, variable = v3, from_= -3.141592, to= 3.141592, orient=HORIZONTAL, digit=5)
wx3.pack()


mainloop()`
```

I am expecting to fix my code to be able to move the sliding bars in different positions (values), in the same canvas, for real values, to be able to do operation with the values from the sliding bar.

Comment: The variable option requires that you pass it a tkinter variable (`StringVar`, `DoubleVar`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
v1 = float()
v2 = float()
v3 = float()
```

to:

```
v1 = tk.DoubleVar()
v2 = tk.DoubleVar()
v3 = tk.DoubleVar()
```

Screenshot:

[image]